# Clearing input-map of a JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I chased down some keyboard problems to `JSplitPane` eating my cursor keys for `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`. I *saw* those entries in the step debugger. But when is the input map actually populated? Because if I try to clear it, there is nothing there...

```scala
val sp = new javax.swing.JSplitPane(orient, left, right)
val map = sp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
map.clear()
```

Then that map is already empty. So it must be filled at a later point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it doesn't directly answer my question, it solves my problem:

```
UIManager.getDefaults.remove("SplitPane.ancestorInputMap")
```